# Send Push notification to multiple device in single request "google/apiclient"

Tags: laravel, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-api-php-client

I have implemented `google/apiclient` in Laravel. I want to send push notifications to multiple device in single request.
If I use foreach loop then it will create request for each token in array.

```
$notification = new Notification([
   'title' => $data['title'],
   'body' => $data['message']
]);

  
$message = new Message([
   'notification' => $notification,
   'data' => $data,
    'token' => $token
]);

$request = new FirebaseCloudMessaging\SendMessageRequest();
$request->setMessage($message);

$messaging = new FirebaseCloudMessaging($this->client);
$response = $messaging->projects_messages->send('projects/my-project', $request);
```

Above is sending push to only one device at a time. I need solution for multiple devices.

It sends notification to one device at a time. I tried with foreach loop but it create new request for each device token.

```
 foreach ($tokens as $token){
            $message = new Message([
                'notification' => $notification,
                'data' => $data,
                'token' => $token
            ]);
            $request = new FirebaseCloudMessaging\SendMessageRequest();
            $request->setMessage($message);
            $messaging = new FirebaseCloudMessaging($this->client);
            $response = $messaging->projects_messages->send('projects/my-project', $request);
          
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you move out `$request = new FirebaseCloudMessaging\SendMessageRequest();` outside, before the loop?

Comment: It sends notification to only last token